# How can I set the swappiness value of the Linux kernel with Nixos?

Tags: nixos

Following the brief mention of `vm.swappiness` in https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/options.html:

I've tried setting:

```
  boot.kernel.sysctl = { "vm.swappiness" = 0;};
```

Within the usual `hardware-configuration.nix`. And I then did a `nixos-rebuild switch` and a reboot.

However I don't see that value being set in `/etc/sysctl.d/nixos.conf`?

In addition:

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
60
```

Comment: Is this still not working for you @chris-stryczynski? This is working just fine for me putting exactly this in the main `configuration.nix` without rebooting (stateVersion `18.03` fwiw). Are you sure your `hardware-configuration.nix` is included properly?

Comment: I just checked, it now is appearing in `/etc/sysctl.d/nixos.conf`. Strange.